# Are there international ferries between Pontianak/Borneo and neighbouring countries?

Tags: ferries, southeast-asia, indonesia, borneo

I'm "planning an unplanned trip" around Asia starting in about a week and I keep finding out I've got more travel friends around the place who I should try to visit.

I want to avoid flying as much as possible because I love ferries and I hate airports.

The usual places such as Wikivoyage and Wikitravel don't offer much details on the ferry connections from West Kalimantan, Indonesia generally and Pontianak specifically though they do make it seem there are ferries. In particular I can't see if there are ferries connecting to any of the other nearby countries. The English on those pages is quite poor in fact.

I'd like to know any/all ferry connections to this city and/or province of Indonesia so if there's a site with those details would be a good answer. I suppose a community wiki might make sense if it turns out to be a list of individual answers.

Answer (score 3):

Planning an unplanned trip, eh?

But seriously, there is only Singapore, Malaysia and Vietnam. The short way to Malaysia would be over land, towards Kuching. One of the [larger ship operators](http://www.pelni.co.id/scheduleresult.php) doesn't go [directly abroad from Borneo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPelni_Schifffahrtsnetz_2006.png), but you can go to Jakarta, then Sumatra and go on from there.

Be aware that the ferries there are in terrible conditions, [often have accidents](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/breaking-news/ferry-and-freighter-collide-in-philippines/story-fn3dxix6-1226698818071) and the distances are up to 1500km. A 30 minute flight might be preferable on many levels to 4-5 days on these ships.

Comment: Yeah I know I'm starting in KL but can't / don't want to figure out all the details in advance (depending on whether I get visas, missing cheap flight windows etc), but I'm trying to get a feel for what is and isn't possible. So planning but not planning (-: